# Java - Send a method as parameter and decide if there is need to call it

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am currently making an app and I am implementing cache in it. The thing is the DAOs are implemented in another service. 
The idea that I had, to avoid code repeating, is having a generic cache in my service. Then, acording to the method called it verifies the respective cache and, in case it doesn't exist, calls the DAO associated with the method passed as parameter. Is there any way to do this?
NOTE: I am using java 1.6 in my application

Comment: With Java 1.8 you could use the `Function` interface. Other than that you need to do it the old way with a self constructed `Interface` as a callback.

Comment: What does "the DAO associated with the method" mean?  If the method is on the DAO class, it's essentially passing the DAO as the parameter. If the method is on some other class, what does it do? Why do you have to get to the DAO thru this method?

Comment: @MuratK. can you pls show me an example just to get better the idea?

Comment: @jingx for example i have 3 types of dao: A, B and C. in A i have getA(), in B i have getB(), in C i have getC(). 
So, basically i want to send to my generic cache the question:
"do you have the item A?" and it goes to search in the cache associated with object A, if it does not have calls the getA() from dao A.

Comment: This is just to prevent me to write 3 classes with interfaces associated with them, and make duplicated code. As what differs here basically is the type and method call to get the items.

Comment: So getA/B/C must have exactly the same signature, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to pass them in for the cache to call in any generic way. Then why hard-code the result type A/B/C in the method names? Why not just have a generic super interface with a method getMyGenericType()?  Then you can pass a reference to this interface to the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need an Adapter pattern. Naive realisation could be

```
class AdapterA implements Adapter<A> {
   private A;
   @Override
   public void getValue() { return getA();}
}
```

and then when you get instance of A, B or C you wrap it in appropriate Adapter. Later you could call just getValue regardless specific type under hood.

Another approach. I would be grateful if someone say what the pattern is (possibly Proxy?):

```
class ProxyImpl implements Proxy {
 @Override
 public void doAction(<? extends DAO> dao) {
   if (dao instance of A) { ((A)dao).getA()
   } else if (dao instance of B) { ((B)dao).getB()
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is just what i needed.